# (Python) ColabTurtle requires has initializeturtle() error, but we already used it

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

code:

```js
import ColabTurtle.Turtle as tutel
tutel.initializeTurtle()
tutel.forward(10)
```

error is:

```js
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\stuff\e.py", line 3, in <module>
    tutel.forward(10)
  File "C:\Users\U.S.E.R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ColabTurtle\Turtle.py", line 174, in forward
    _moveToNewPosition(ending_point)
  File "C:\Users\U.S.E.R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ColabTurtle\Turtle.py", line 163, in _moveToNewPosition
    _updateDrawing()
  File "C:\Users\U.S.E.R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ColabTurtle\Turtle.py", line 144, in _updateDrawing    
    raise AttributeError("Display has not been initialized yet. Call initializeTurtle() before using.")
AttributeError: Display has not been initialized yet. Call initializeTurtle() before using.
```

basically, it tells me to use intializeturtle() before running a ColabTurtle function. Except, i did already use it.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it in Google Collab. If there will be no module ColabTurtle, you need to create a new code (+code) and write

```
!pip install ColabTurtle
```